# Назначить стиль ListViewItem конкретному ListView xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-стили

На форме есть три ListView. Каждому ListView нужно добавить разную анимацию добавления элементов. В ResourceDictionary создаю несколько стилей для ListViewItem так:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="SlideRightStyle">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="transform" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2"
                                         From="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:.2"
                                         From="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleX" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Проблема в том, что указанный стиль автоматически применяется всем ListView на форме. Как указать стиль конкретному ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SlideRightStyle}">
    ...
</ListView>
```